# Interchange limit and integral when limit affects limits of integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given an integral of the form
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{2t}\int_{-t}^{+t} dx f(t,x)$$ 
under what conditions can it be rewritten as 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{2t} f(t,x)$$ 
and why?

Comment: What is $f_t?\,$

Comment: A function of $x$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0):

$f_{t}(x)$ must be continuous and converge uniformly on $[-t, t]$.

Comment: Thanks, can I see a proof? Obviuosly that'd mean the $f$ should converge uniformly (almost) everywhere.

Comment: What does converging uniformly on a moving target like $[-t,t]$ even mean?